# Desenvolver em C# e .NET no Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu, mono

Recentemente tive que migrar do Windows para o Linux, pois meu notebook de trabalho queimou e estou usando um antigo com Intel Atom e apenas 2GB de RAM, fiquei inseguro de usar o Windows por ser um equipamento bem fraco.

Tenho que trabalhar com C# e .NET, andei pesquisando sobre possibilidades para poder usar, segue as encontradas:

- Usar MonoDevelop, não sei muito bem as restrições para seu uso, porém em pesquisas sempre tem usuários falando que não funciona muito bem.
- Máquina virtual do Windows, fora de questão por ser um equipamento fraco.

Quero saber se há mais opções, se não o houver, quais são as restrições do Mono?

Comment: Como dito, vá de Visual Studio Code. Leve e vc pode desenvolver com .NET Core tranquilamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar o [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) à vontade, sem restrições, igual ao Mono. Ele é bom, só não é fantástico. Acredito que hoje quase todo mundo vai optar por ele nessas condições impostas. De fato agora ele ficou mais livre depois que a Microsoft passou ser proprietária.

Cada dia o [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) fica em um nível mais interessante.

A JetBrains desenvolveu um [IDE novo baseado no IntelliJ e Resharper](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/01/13/project-rider-a-csharp-ide/) que vai rodar no Linux.

Já ouvi falar de *plugins* para Eclipse, mas nunca vi um.

Fora isso tem editores simples com serviços para C#. Dificilmente vão fazer muito melhor que o VS Code. Vai do gosto e costume.

De qualquer forma máquinas pouco potentes para rodar IDE complica um pouco. Alguma coisa não ficará bem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Retirei o final, já usei o Mono no Windows, etc, tomara que atenda as expectativas no Linux. Realmente é complicado trabalhar em máquina fraca, ser sem sorte é osso kk

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o monodevelop foi descontinuado, mas com o novo movimento da Microsoft, acredito que ele tomou nova forma, inclusive pela nova acessibilidade do .NET nas distribuições LINUX.

O antigo site do [MonoDevelop](https://www.monodevelop.com/) deixou a antiga IDE descontinuada

Este novo site mostra as novas builds e releases do projeto.
https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/

Aparentemente, é possível utilizar todas as funcionalidades por aqui, incluindo o xamarin, no ubuntu.